# How to determine if code is running in a command-line tool or in a GUI app?

Tags: objective-c, foundation

I'm writing a Mac app with two targets - a regular Cocoa GUI and a Foundation command-line tool.  They do very similar things other than the GUI, so I'm sharing most of the code between the two.

I'd like to do a few things slightly differently depending on which target is running.  I can think of many ways to do this (#define something in the pch, check for existence of GUI definitions...).  I'm curious if there's a standard or recommended way to do this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest structuring the code in three pieces: the GUI app, the command line tool, and a library they both link against that does the actual work. You can then have API in the library for configuring it, and have the command line tool and the app use the API differently as appropriate.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I'm doing thus far (the "two targets" referred to above).  Works perfectly fine.  This is somewhat of a theoretical question as to a better way to do it, which would make the library independent of the target-specific code.

Comment: Nothing better comes to mind. You could detect it in various ways, but I think explicit configuration from each client program will be easier to understand in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard practice for separation of responsibilities in object-oriented programming: [model view controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). When you follow this pattern, you are not likely to need to know whether your code is running in a command-line environment or a graphical user interface environment. If you believe you have a case where this is necessary to distinguish, please describe the situation.

Even if you need to distinguish the two scenarios, you should have some unique property in each executable that can be passed in as a parameter. For example, say you want to log the screen size. For a foundation command-line tool, you may want the screen size as X/Y dimensions in the number of fixed-width characters (e.g. 80x25), but in a GUI, you want the pixel count (e.g. 1280x1024). Create your interface with this expectation, such as:

```
- (CGSize)screenSizeForAppContext:(int)context
{
    // You could define 0 to mean command-line tool, 1 to mean GUI app
    if (0 == context) {
        // return screen size by characters
    } else if (1 == context) {
        // return screen size by pixels
    }
    return CGSizeZero;
}
```